# Using chrome.browserAction.setPopup per tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension which dynamically changes the content of the popup window based on the current URL.

I'm doing something like this in background.js, which works fine:

```
if(domains.contains(request.url)){
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup: "tracking.html"
    });
}else{
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup: "nottracking.html"
    });
}
```

The problem is that if I switch tab, the content of the popup stays the same between tabs. What's the correct strategy to deal with this?

- Hook into the tab change event somehow (if such a possibility exists)?
- Limit the change of popup contents to the current tab? (I did notice that there's an optional `tabId` parameter for chrome.browserAction.setPopup, but the docs are a bit scant)
- Something else?

All help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option 1, bind an event listener:

Use [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) to listen for URI changes, followed by [`chrome.browserAction.setPopup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setPopup) with a given `tabId` to set the popup for the given tab. For example:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (domains.contains(tab.url)) {
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
            tabId: tabId,
            popup: 'tracking.html'
        });
    } else {
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
            tabId: tabId,
            popup: 'nottracking.html'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply pass the TabId to the setPopup call. http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html

I do this in my background page all the time:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({"tabId":data.tabId,"popup":url});
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

[The `setpopup` parameter's object now supports a `tabId` value.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setPopup)
You'll need to get the numeric id of the current tab first. This does not require additional permissions.

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    var url = domains.contains(request.url) ? "tracking.html" : "nottracking.html";
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
       popup: url,
       tabId: tabs[0].id
    });
});
```

Comment: That said, you might be interested in document.location.replace("foo.html"). But I'm not sure that it wouldn't be for all tabs either.