# Changing the popup.html through options, in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm quite new to this. I need to change the popup.html that gets shown in my chrome extension.
I have two popup.htmls. I also need to save the value of the users choice.

My options.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="options.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <label class="paylabel" for="cardtype">Theme:</label>
 <select id="cardtype" name="cards">
 <option value="selectcard">--- Please select ---</option>
 <option value="op1">first</option>
 <option value="op2">second</option>
 </select>

<input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="click here">
 </body>
 </html>
```

options.js:

```
   function fun()
  {
   var ddl = document.getElementById("cardtype");
   var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
   if (selectedValue == "op2")
  {
 chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
         popup: 'popup2.html'
     });
   }
  }
```

My manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "extension name",
"options_page": "options.html",
 ...
 }
```

This question is not a duplicate, because in my question I'm trying to figure out how to display different popup.htmls according to the users choice. The other question is trying to identify why the onclick function doesn't work within the chrome extension.

Comment: what exactly is required? is your html is not loaded on plugin?
Any change in manifest & html require re-installation of plugin to chrome

Comment: no, I have two popup.htmls. I want the user to be able to choose between the two.

Comment: if i could understood you correctly, then you want a configuration for user to choose, which view they want. then you could add a input field on a common html, which will then redirect to either popup based on preference.

Comment: That could work. This is what I originally wanted: I wanted the user to go to the options choose the popup, which would set the popup.html (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setPopup)

Comment: Cool.. You could try this then, enjoy your day.. :)

Comment: Umm.. I did try that, but that's the problem it's not working. Check out my code. Thanks, you too :)

Comment: This link could help you understanding the logic to use setPopup method. [Check example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071357/using-chrome-browseraction-setpopup-per-tab)

Comment: @Ahan, inline javascript doesn't work inside chrome extension's pages like options.html

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah, I thought it wouldn't can you please tell me what to do then? I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry @wOxxOm, that's not what I meant. My code is still not working. It's not changing to popup2.html

Comment: @wOxxOm I've added it.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If you know the answer, can you post it?

Comment: `fun()` in your html is an inline javascript. You may easily google it, for example: [this](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I figured it out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working)

Comment: @wOxxOm I had also asked how I could save it, I've asked the question here, do you know how to do this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806467/local-storage-is-being-erased-in-chrome-extension