# Local storage is being erased in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

So I want to save the theme the user chooses, and accordingly I'm choosing the popup to show them. 
Every time I close my tab (after 3 times) or quit chrome, it forgets my choice.

My options.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="options.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,200,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <label class="paylabel" for="cardtype">Theme:</label>
    <select id="cardtype" name="cards">
      <option value="selectcard">--- Please select ---</option>
      <option value="op1">Theme 1</option>
      <option value="op2">Theme 2</option>
    </select>
  </center>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <h1 style="font-family:Raleway; font-weight:200; float:left">Theme 1</h1>
    <h1 style="font-family:Raleway; font-weight:200; float:Right">Theme 2</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  <img src = "screen2.png"; alt="" style="float:left"/>

  <img src = "screen1.png"; alt="" style="float:right"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Options.js:

```
time=setInterval(function(){
  var ddl = document.getElementById("cardtype");
  var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
  localStorage["inputText"] = selectedValue;
  var myvar = localStorage["inputText"];
    if (myvar == "op2")
   {
     chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
             popup: 'popup.html'
         });
   }
   else{
     chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
             popup: 'popup2.html'
         });
   }
},1000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `setInterval`. Use a proper method like `ddl.onchange = function(e) { ....... };`

Comment: Ok, just that isn't working what else do I need to do? Thanks

Comment: You need to try implementing it and use [the debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) in case of problems.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I just can seem to figure it out. My popups don't change unless I use the serInterval. Can you help or answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move `<script src="options.js"></script>` before the closing `</body>` tag so that the script code will execute only when the entire document is parsed and loaded.
2. Instead of `setInterval` use a proper on-change listener.

```
var element = document.getElementById("cardtype");

element.value = localStorage.inputText || 'op1';

element.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    localStorage.inputText = selectedValue;
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup: selectedValue == 'op1' ? 'popup.html' : 'popup2.html'
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, the code doesn't seem to be working for me. Even if I put a alert, it doesn't run for me.

Comment: I should be able to get a popup alert if I put a alert in my js code (after the event listener), right?

Comment: Sorry your code isn't saving the value in local storage

Comment: Great, it's saving the option now, but when I restart chrome, it doesn't check for the previous option.

Comment: Thanks, you're really close. It's working great except when I restart chrome, then (even though its being saved), it doesn't show the correct popup.

Comment: So it's working perfectly fine if i restart chrome, and the options.html page gets opened, but if I restart chrome and google.com opens, then the code doesn't run, and therefore, it doesn't read the correct popup.html

Comment: @Ahan, I'm sorry, but how do you think the options page can do it? Obviously you should read `localStorage.inputText` and apply the correct popup in the extension's **background script**.